# Joining tuple elements - list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7

We have this:

```
lst = [('543', 'Tom', '- Jerry'), ('544', 'X-man - ', 'Hulk')]`
lst = [h+a for n,h,a in lst]
lst =[name.split(' - ') for name in lst]
```

I want to first, join `[1]` and `[2]` element in each tuple together and split them on the `-` Splitting code will work but list comprehension for joining them does not.

We want the final output to be:

`[('534', 'Tom, 'Jerry'), ('544', 'X-man', 'Hulk')]`

With the code above we get only:

`[('Tom, 'Jerry'), ('X-man', 'Hulk')]`

**@EDIT**

I have another problem:
sometimes my tuples contain only 2 items like this (2nd tuple):
`[('534', 'Tom, 'Jerry'), ('544', 'X-man - Hulk')]`
I want to get rid of the `-` so with the list comprehension from below I came up with this modified version:
`lst = [tuple(i.split(' - ') if len(tup) == 2 else tuple(i.strip(' - ') for i in tup) for tup in lst]` which however raises an `invalid syntax` exception.

I'm sorry guys for asking again about similar issue but list comprehension is quite a new concept to me but if I get right the above I'll finish my program so I'm too impatient to study the whole documentation on the topic right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I am wrong, but do you really just want to strip off the whitespace and '-'?

```
In [15]: lst = [('543', 'Tom', '- Jerry'), ('544', 'X-man - ', 'Hulk')]

In [16]: [tuple(i.strip(' -') for i in tup) for tup in lst]
Out[16]: [('543', 'Tom', 'Jerry'), ('544', 'X-man', 'Hulk')]
```

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to get rid of the `-` Thanks!

Comment: @nutship If you want to strip off the `-`, root's solution is cleaner

Comment: @ root can you spare a glance once more on the 1st post, since I have another, similar problem please.

Comment: @nutship - how do you get the input? what you are doing right now is going to get unmaintainable quite quickly...